# Which is correct "When do you start for London?" or "When does you start for London?"

Tags: grammatical-number

Its quite confusing to me whether to use singular or plural verb in the above sentence. Will that be depending on the Subject "you" based on if it is singular or plural? Can anybody enlighten me?

Comment: Use plural verb for "you".

Comment: 'you' takes only plural verb. Like you are, you were, etc.

Comment: Could you explain why you think it might be 'does you'?  [an inversion of 'you does' which is clearly incorrect].  At first sight this is an elementary mistake. I am wondering if you have some deeper reason for asking. Please can you give more details of your reasoning?  EDIT - on re-reading, you appear to believe that 2nd person singular and plural have different verb forms - they don't.

Answer (score 2):

It's always ***You are ...***, ***You do ...***, ***You have ...*** (as far as auxiliary verbs go).
So in your example, use ***When do you*** ...?

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You) says,

> In standard English, *you* is both singular and plural; it always takes a verb form that originally marked the word as plural, (i.e. *you are*, in common with *we are* and *they are*).